# Multiline Regex when the format change

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to code a parser for log files in python and I'm struggling with the Regex.

This is an extract of my log files, of course there are thousands of entries like those:

```
//
JOBINC/PSEUDO:MIKE/NAME:MICKAEL/HEIGHT:1.8M/JOB:DEV//
UPDATE/MAY 2021//
DEV/WORK:256695H1587469K/WORK:364525H6715369K/WORK:9842645H1364595K/
WORK:549812H6845354K/WORK:284568H5898758K//
WORKPLACE/MELBOURNE//
WORKPERIOD/MAY-MAY/05MAY2008/05MAY2021//
//
JOBINC/PSEUDO:JAY/NAME:JEROME/HEIGHT:1.64/JOB:ATHLETE//
UPDATE/MAY 2021//
ATHLETE/WORK:123658H4578125K/WORK:157456H8431567K/WORK:124856H6483256K 
WORK:152345H1345126K/WORK:198458H3615207H/WORK:678045H0630251K/
WORK:159036H1753158K/WORK:058845H1658435K//
WORKPLACE/GENEVA//
WORKPERIOD/MAY-MAY/18MAY2008/23MAY2021//
//
```

The idea is to create a DataFrame based on those logs.
The colums of the DataFrame are : "JOBINC", "PSEUDO", "NAME", "HEIGHT", "JOB", "WORK", "WORKPLACE", "WORKPERIOD".

This is the regex I have until now but it doesn't work. By example, the numbers of "WORK:" entries is different each time and I can't get them all.

```
(JOBINC)/(PSEUDO:.*?(?=/))/(NAME:.*?(?=/))/(HEIGHT:.*?(?=/))/(JOB:.*?(?=/))//
UPDATE/MAY 2021//
(.*?(?=/))/(WORK:.*?(?=/))
```

What am I missing to select everything I need ?

Thank you for helping,

Comment: I recommend you to go to https://regexr.com/ and try to find which is the issue in you regex by yourself. You can paste the text and try to build your regex incrementally.

In any case, what you are missing for matching elements in the following line is the newline character (`\n`).

Also, if you don't know how many occurrences of WORK you'll have you can use the `+` operator, to match one or more occurrences:
`((.*?(?=/))/(WORK:.*?(?=/)))+`.

Comment: It seems you're using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, haven't you considered just splitting by '//', '/', and ':'??

Comment: I tought about it but the problem is that the format is not fixed. By example, the number of occurences of WORK: changes depending on the individual. Or I am missing something ?

Comment: I don't see that as a limitation, it depends on how much you know about *Regex* and if it's easy for you to maintain it.